# Hexagonal circle packings in the plane

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

I have been reading the paper [*Spiral hexagonal circle packings in the plane*](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01263534.pdf) (Alan F. Beardon, Tomasz Dubejko and Kenneth Stephenson, Geometriae Dedicata Volume 49, Issue 1, pp 39-70), which proves that “these ’coherent’ [Doyle] spirals, together with the regular hexagonal packing, give all possible hexagonal circle packings in the plane”.

On the obvious reading, this claim is straightforwardly false. For example there is a double spiral hexagonal packing obtained as a Möbius transformation of the Doyle spiral, as illustrated here [by Francesco De Comité](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fdecomite/2357432848/):

[image: Double spiral]

Am I interpreting the claim incorrectly? How ought it to be understood?

Comment: I haven't read the paper closely but it seems like the authors address your concerns in Section 6.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks. Certainly Section 6 is the relevant section. Hmm, is the point that their notion of equivalence is combinatorial, so that two circle packings are equivalent in their sense if they have isomorphic tangency graphs?

Comment: According to http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~bobenko/papers/2001_Bob_Hof.pdf: “It is an open question whether Doyle spirals are the only entire circle packings”.