# What is the equation to evenly distribute circles in a spiral?

Tags: circles, packing-problem

What is the equation to evenly distribute circles in a spiral?  I have attached a picture to show what I am trying to achieve and need to know what the equation is for this.

[image]

Comment: These are Soddy Circles http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerSoddyCircle.html

Comment: This is called a Doyle spiral. Best reference at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This packing is diagram 5(b) on the fifth page of [Stephenson](http://www.math.utk.edu/~kens/Notices_article.pdf)   and is attributed to Doyle. However, Peter Doyle. Hmmm. Well, Doyle spirals are discussed at length in the [BOOK](https://books.google.com/books?id=38PxEmKKhysC&pg=PA325&dq=self%20similarity%20Doyle%20%20spiral%20%20circles&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pAk3VbPTLYOeyASAtoHYBw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=self%20similarity%20Doyle%20%20spiral%20%20circles&f=false)

Evidently the most detail is in the article mentioned in [Hexagonal circle packings in the plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454176/hexagonal-circle-packings-in-the-plane)
with the article being http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01263534?no-access=true  Beardon, Dubejko, Stephenson, *Spiral hexagonal circle packings in the plane*, Geometriae Dedicata, January 1994, Volume 49, issue 1, pages 39-70